# Is there a maven plugin to clean unused dependencies

Tags: gradle, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am using a maven since from a long time and I can see that my repository gets clutter from various dependencies with various unused versions. 
Is there any maven plugin that can clear my unused jars or dependencies from my repositories? 
I may agree that we may have a several project dependencies in the maven repository(.m2/repository) but there must be some way to clean the unused jars or dependency versions that are no longer used.

Is gradle gives this flexibility?

Comment: Just delete the entire folder, what is required will be downloaded again. There is no way for any plugin or software to look at the repository and determine which ones were used recently. It might be possible to determine which ones were downloaded recently, but that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Yep but that what I don't want to do. Reason, if I have a several projects, I have many dependencies in my central repository and deleting one means that I have to download again the dependencies for all the project.